# Change hover color when mouse clicks on button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to change the hover color when the mouse clicks on the button but I got an error via the browser , check below.

The browser result :

```
VM898 home.php:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'link-privacy-policy' of undefined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (VM898 home.php:62)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.handle (jquery-3.4.0.js:5707)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.4.0.js:5233)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.4.0.js:5040)
```

*Jquery code*

```
<script>
    let color_count = 0;
    let colors = [{
        "name": "blue",
        "btn-change-color": "#7f8ff4",
        "btn-start": "#7f8ff4",
        "link-privacy-policy": "#7f8ff4"
    },
        {
            "name": "orange",
            "btn-change-color": "#f8d745",
            "btn-start": "#f8d745",
            "link-privacy-policy": "#f8d745"
        }];
    let btnChangeColor = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-change-color");
    let btnStart = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-start");
    let linkPrivacyPolicy = document.getElementsByClassName("link-privacy-policy");
    $(".btn-change-color").click(function () {
        $(btnChangeColor).css("background", colors[color_count]["btn-change-color"]);
        $(btnStart).css("background", colors[color_count]["btn-start"]);
        $(linkPrivacyPolicy).hover(function () {
            $(this).css('color', colors[color_count]["link-privacy-policy"]);
            $(this).css('border-bottom', '1px solid ' + colors[color_count]["link-privacy-policy"]);
        })
        color_count++;
    });
</script>
```

> Note : Line 62 starts with this line : 
>   $(this).css('color', colors[color_count]["link-privacy-policy"]);

Comment: Well, every time the user clicks, `color_count` is incremented.  This only needs to happen twice before the index gets out of bounds of the array, which is what is happening here. Do you want `color_count` to go back to 0 when it reaches the end of the array?

Comment: Maybe try `color_count = (color_count + 1) % colors.length;` so it will loop through the array

Comment: @RobinZigmond Yes I know that but It's for test when number be 1 or orange color the error showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Here you have a table `colors` with 2 object and when user click the `color_count` increment then you should add a condition to fix that:

```
    $(".btn-change-color").click(function () {
            $(btnChangeColor).css("background", colors[color_count]["btn-change-color"]);
            $(btnStart).css("background", colors[color_count]["btn-start"]);
            $(linkPrivacyPolicy).hover(function () {
                $(this).css('color', colors[color_count]["link-privacy-policy"]);
                $(this).css('border-bottom', '1px solid ' + colors[color_count]["link-privacy-policy"]);
            });
            color_count++;
            //You will add this condition
            if(color_count >= colors.length)
                 color_count = 0;

        });
```

Comment: Yes I know that but It's for test when number be 1 or orange color the error showing

Comment: Yes bro and note that the getElementsByClassName() return an array then you should linkPrivacyPolicy[0] for example...

Answer (score 1):

Deciphering error messages can be confusing sometimes:

```
 Cannot read property 'link-privacy-policy' of undefined
```

This effectively means that the following code...

```
 colors[color_count]["link-privacy-policy"]
```

...throws an error because `colors[color_count]` evaluates to `undefined` -- so naturally that value has no property `link-privacy-policy`.

@Robin Zigmond's comment (added while I typed this answer) may explain why you're hitting `undefined`